# SSIS For Each Item Loop reading same file during recursion

Tags: sql-server, recursion, ssis

I've been attempting to pull in a list of files using a For Each Item Loop using several methods (VB Script, straight for each loop with flat file connection and even execute process task for cmd line scan).

What I notice is that I tend to get the same file listed several times when I enable the data viewer.

Is this common for SSIS/For each loop?

Also, when I attempt to import this list into a SQL table (after filtering out duplicates) I'm only receiving a partial list of the files getting inventoried.

I have to assume that there is an issue with the recursion into my variable causing the variable to hold the same file/path for several "passes".

Here's my attempt...
For Each
[image]

Variable Mapping
[image]

SQL Statement for Insert
[image]

parameter mapping
[image]

Variables

[image]

Comment: Are you certain the loop is doing this?  Try disabling everything inside the loop, and adding a script task which pops a messagebox showing the variable value... I would also pop a messagebox on that function which references the variable -- ensure it is updating on every iteration too.

Comment: I added some breaks to the for each loop - when the loop finished each cycle the variables change and seem to match.  I only watched the first 10 or so though...

Comment: You might need to show more of what you're doing in the package then.  I've never used a function to access a variable, but if you're saying its updating I believe you.  I don't see anything standing out that would cause the variable to be static through iterations... you might try just using the variable twice instead of the function.

Comment: Apologies if my previous answer caused any confusion. @DaveCullum was correct that indexes start at 0, as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/map-query-parameters-to-variables-in-an-execute-sql-task?view=sql-server-2014
Also, he is correct in suggesting to use the same variable for both parameters in your `Execute SQL Task`.

Comment: I'll remove the function and test.  I believe I tried this before with the same results but I'll double check.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was some sort of limitation from the NAS.
Ended up using Execute Process Task with cmd.exe and arguments.
Seems like anything that ran faster caused data issues.

Summary of testing if this may help someone down the road:

1. Execute Process with cmd = fastest w/ complete data
2. Execute Process with Power Shell=(get child) slower w/ complete data
3. Execute Process with Power Shell=(Enum Files) Fastest with data loss
4. SSIS For Each Loop = Slow Erratic data (duplicate and Loss)